# Is there a way to change directory of config files in Anaconda/Spyder?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

When installed and then opened, both platforms create the following folders in the %UserProfile% directory...

(e.g.: "C:\Users\[username]):

- ".spyder-py3"
- ".anaconda"
- ".conda"
- ".config"
- ".ipython"
- ".matplotlib"

I've got my working folder in, say, the following path: "B:\Python". I want to have the aforementioned folders stored in said path, and the Anaconda and Spyder platforms to still be able to find them. Where do I modify the paths from the default one (user profile) to the new one ("B:\Python")?

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) No, there isn't, sorry.